# Boolean Algebra Simplification

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How do I simplify the following equation?
$\newcommand{\pn}{\phantom{\neg}}$
$$\begin{align*}
\neg A\pn B \neg C \neg D\\
+ \pn A\neg B\neg C\neg D\\
+ \neg A\neg B\neg C\pn D\\
+ \pn A\pn B\neg C\pn D\\
+ \neg A\pn B\pn C\pn D\\
+ \pn A\neg B\pn C\pn D\\
+ \neg A\neg B\pn C\neg D\\
+ \pn A\pn B\pn C\neg D
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Does 'AB' mean 'A and B'? Does 'A+B' mean exclusive or?

Comment: Sorry mate AB means A and B, A+B means A or B cheers

Comment: @Sammy Then where are your brackets? `and` and `or` are not associative together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the brackets are meant to be around all `and`-blocks, the statement is equivalent to
$D$ being the parity bit for information $ABC$, i.e.
$$D = \neg(A\oplus B \oplus C)\\
\Leftrightarrow A\oplus B \oplus C\oplus D$$
Where $\oplus$ is `xor`

Comment: @Sammy May I ask where this question arose?

Comment: Part of an assignment - I was moving swiftly through the early parts but this popped up and as it happens Boolean algebra is my Achilles' heel!! Thanks again  - you really saved my bacon!

Comment: Actually, could you please give me an idea of how you worked this question out so that I don't get stuck in the future? Thank you.

Comment: @Sammy As you can see, I formatted it to show exactly wich combinations are valid. Then I noticed that $A, B, C$ are listed in all possible combinations with exactly one value of $D$. Remained to find out how $D$ relates to the values of $ABC$ if I want a valid combination.

Answer (score 0):

Any propositional expression could be expressed by $1$ (true), $+$ (exclusive or) and $\cdot$ (and). Expressing an expression this way makes it straightforward to simplify by ordinary algebraic laws and calculations, just remembering that $S+S=0$ and $S\cdot S=S$ for all $S$.

1. $\neg S$ is replaced with $1+S$
2. $S\Rightarrow T$ is replaced with $1+S+S\cdot T$
3. $S\Leftrightarrow T$ is replaced with $1+S\cdot T$
4. $S \vee T$ is replaced with $S+T+S\cdot T$

In this case, this method would be clumsy, but it always work.